# How I create a simples questionnaire with Lita.io?

Tags: ruby, chatbot, lita

I try implementing a little questionnaire in Lita as the sample:

> **For which system do you want to open a call?**
>
> SYSInitials
>
> **What's your problem?**
>
> I forgot my password
>
> **Thanks! Your call was opened!**

Any help how I can do this?

So, I'm try this:

```
module Lita
  module Handlers
    class Helpdesk < Handler
      on :shut_down_complete, :clear_context

      route(/^abrir chamado$/i, :abrir_chamado)
      route(/^.*$/i, :motivo)
      http.get '/info', :web

      def motivo(response)
        return unless context == 'abrir_chamado'
        response.reply('Thanks! Your call was opened!')
        clear_context
      end

      def abrir_chamado(response)
        redis.set(:context, :abrir_chamado)
        user = response.user
        response.reply(
          %(Hello #{user.name}, What is your problem?)
        )
      end

      def context
        @contetx ||= redis.get(:context)
      end

      def clear_context
        redis.del(:context)
      end

      Lita.register_handler(Helpdesk)
    end
  end
end
```

But when I register, `:informar_motivo route`, after passing of the `:abrir_chamado route`, is matched `:informar_motivo` route too.

[image: lita dialog flux]

but I need:

> **me:** abrir chamado
>
> **Lita:** Hello Shell User, What is your problem?
>
> **me:** I forgot my password
>
> **Lita:** Thanks! Your call was opened!

Answer (score 0):

I found a ugly solution, but works  :P

```
module Lita
  module Handlers
    class Helpdesk < Handler
      on :shut_down_complete, :clear_context
      on :unhandled_message, :motivo

      route(/^abrir chamado$/i, :abrir_chamado)

      http.get '/info', :web

      def motivo(payload)
        response = payload[:message]
        return unless context == 'abrir_chamado'
        response.reply('Thanks! Your call was opened!')
        clear_context
      end

      def abrir_chamado(response)
        redis.set(:context, :abrir_chamado)
        user = response.user
        response.reply(
          %(Hello #{user.name}, What is your problem?)
        )
      end

      def context
        @contetx ||= redis.get(:context)
      end

      def clear_context
        redis.del(:context)
      end

      Lita.register_handler(Helpdesk)
    end
  end
end
```

[image]